# Pie chart changing weekly

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a chart of every week in a year with information about how many hours, 9 people are working. Is it possible to make this into a weekly pie chart that automaticly shows the current week and percentage of total hours everyone is working i.e a workload pie chart auto updating to the current week.

[Current graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr8fb.jpg)

[What I want](http://imgur.com/3P3Sj5b)

The data is taken from a calendar where everyone puts in their hours per week per project. [From this calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLa5m.png)

I don't even know how to start with the code so I don't have any code for the pie chart.

This is how the current year overview graph is set up [graph for hours a week for every person](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGAMZdG)

This is formula for the hours `=SUMIFS(Calendarsheet!L4:L262;Calendarsheet!$B4:$B262;Calendarsheet!$B4)`
I store names in B column

[graph of percent of their max hours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbebeMb)
Formula in this chart: `=B34/Calendarsheet!L$3`  it takes the hours from the first chart and divides by total workhours of that week taken from the calendarsheet

Sorry for bad links, need more reputation to post more than 2 links

Comment: It is possible to do depending upon how the underlying data is stored.
Can you give us an example of how your data is stored and an example of the code that you have having trouble with?

Comment: The data is taken from a calendar were everyone puts in their hours per week per project. From this calendar: http://i.stack.imgur.com/HLa5m.png

Comment: Added information to the post

Comment: I don't think that you need to use VBA for this. You could enter the week number/date and use Lookups to extract the desired data to a fixed column that hold the source data for the pie charts. Changing the week number will change the pie charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you correctly then you want to extract one column from the calendar each time and present it in a pie chart. So first make an assisting column that will depend on a value stored in a specific cell (say `U2`), then create a pie chart using that column, and every time you will update the cell `U2` your pie chart will update.

For the assisting column you will need `=LOOKUP($U$2,$B$2:$S$2,B5:U5)` where `$B$2:$S$2` is the row with the week numbers and `B5:S5` is the hours for the person in row `5`. You then do this for all persons in the table. Finally you create a pie chart based on this column.

Here you can see the `LOOKUP()` formula in it's place:
[image: Assisting column]

And here the range selected to produce the pie chart (`A4:A12`&`V3:V12`):
[image: Dynamic Pie chart]

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Ty my man it worked flawlessly. I just had to put =RIGHT(YEAR(NOW()),2)*100+WEEKNUM(NOW()) in U2.  Another great and detailed answer :)

Comment: I just have one little question. For some reason excel has the wrong weeks. It is week 28 atm not week 29. Do I just use -1 or are there any weeks were excel is correct?. Nvm ill just use isoweeknum(now()) and it should work fine

Comment: Well, seems like it's a known problem of different ways to count weeks, you can try to use [this explanation](https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/3v55jo/weeknum_numbers_are_wrong_for_2016/) to solve it.

Comment: I used the isoweeknum which is the correct one. The explanation you linked is for older excel version (works with never aswell) but in 2013 excel implemented the isoweeknum system so you dont have to make complicated formula to get the iso 8601